# How to install OpenLayers in drupal?

Tags: openlayers-2, installation, drupal

I have been trying this for a while without success. After installing the OpenLayers module in drupal 7.14 and trying to configure it i get the following error:

Cannot establish a connection to the server:

I have tried all permutations including downloading the openlayers library in the local machine, giving it a local path in a number of different ways.

The second error that is seen suggests that i am installing an incorrect version of the openlayers library when in fact i have been installing the recommended version i.e. version 2.11.

It has been a frustrating experience getting Openlayers, Geoserver , PostGIS and Drupal 7 working together on Windows 7. The number of combinations are many and there are many issues that are difficult to solve if you are not a webmaster.

Comment: Apart from "Cannot establish a connection to the server:" could you provide some more details. OpenLayers doesnt have any server side code. All you have is pure and clear Javascript. It maybe because you are accessing some server side stuff such as GeoServer(as you mentioned in Question). So please check geoserver seperately and then setup OL to use the working configuration of geoserver and finally go back to drupal